# Transaction ID not found- Status still unconfirmed after a month?

Tags: transactions, wallet, exchanges, bitstamp

I did a transaction back to my bitstamp account on 23.02.2016 but it has not been received. Transaction ID:

```
1886e0c49ba43a842043fc84358a05d3faf69468c1547e1d2ef3e030b929f834
```

I do have the blockchain located on an external hardrive since it takes up so much space. Any help on how I can get the transaction to go through?

Comment: Which wallet software are you using? Bitcoin-Core?

Answer (score 2):

After 72 hours the transaction will get purged from the mempool if no miner has picked it up. Try resending the funds and include a transaction fee so that the miners will expedite your transaction.